# Custom antialiasing settings in three.js

Tags: three.js, webgl, antialiasing

I am trying to find a way to specify some antialiasing settings in three.js/WebGL to try and improve the results.

The thing is that with the exact same code, if I load a model on a Retina Display, the antialiasing works quite fine (even if I move it to my non-retina external monitor afterwards), but it's all pixelated if I load it first on a non-retina screen.

Here is a screenshot (both on Chrome, both displayed on a retina display). Left was loaded on a non-retina, right on a retina: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EJ0mS.png

What I get from this is that three.js somehow uses the pixel density when initializing the antialiasing. Is there anyway to tweak this so that I can force it to something better?

Thanks a lot in advance for your help :)

---

Side note: For the record, it seems that the antialiasing works much better on Firefox as well, anyone knows why?

Comment: Not a three.js comment. FYI webgl does not allow you to control the level of hardware antialiasing at all. I think what you are seeing that the two pictures are drawn with different native resolution. Google/SO `.devicePixelRatio` and check the whether canvas.width is the same for the 2 different displays. Again, dont know how to do this in three js.

Comment: Yes, I wasn't sure if it was three.js or WebGL, and I couldn't find what to start looking for. Thanks for those indications then!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just in case someone is looking to do the same kind of tweaking I was trying, I'll answer my own question.

Based on WaclawJasper's comment, I found some documentation in Three.js related to my issue. From http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Renderers/WebGLRenderer:

> .setPixelRatio ( value )
>
> Sets device pixel ratio. This is usually used for HiDPI device to prevent blurring output canvas.

I was using `renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );` in my initialization, which was the reason why the rendering was depending on where the page was first *loaded*.

Related to the antialiasing, I now artificially raise the pixel density using `renderer.setPixelRatio(2);` on non-retina screens. This results in a much more effective antialiasing, at the cost of increased computation.

Comment: Know that the difference in what you see is impacted by the way that Apple HiDPI actually works. For the typical retina 15" macbook pro screen, you have a physical 2880x1800 resolution. If you use the default resolution, it will render webpages with device ratio 2 so that a CSS pixel is actually 2 physical pixels (screen at 1440x900 CSS pixels), and three will render at "full physical" resolution if you set devicepixelratio to 2. If you set the system display settings to "More space", that's a 1920x1200 CSS pixel resolution that is internally rendered at 3840x2400.

Comment: Thus if you run the "more space" setting, all your pixel ratio 2 content will actually be slightly supersampled over your screen's physical pixel density. The downscaling that Apple does is very high quality, so overall the result is a very decent one. If you still wonder why it doesn't look exactly the same as on a different OS, then this may be why.